Why the setter for the child class is called when calling super()
I have been struggling with this for few hours now. I thought to seek the help of this community.
I am creating a class to inherit from numpy.ndarray. I also need to create a getter and a setter for the dtype property.
import numpy as np

class myarray(np.ndarray):
    __dtype = None

    def __new__(cls, in_data, dtype):
        obj = np.array(in_data, dtype).view(cls)      
        return obj

    def view(self, dtype = None):
        if dtype is None:
            return self
        else:
            return super().view(np.uint8)
    
    @property
    def dtype(self):
        return self.__dtype
    
    @dtype.setter
    def dtype(self, value):
        print("Setter for dtype in the child class is called!!")

a = myarray([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype = np.uint16)

b = a.view(dtype = np.uint8)

print(b)

When I run this code, I get the following:

Setter for dtype in the child class is called!!
[1 2 3 4]

Why when I call super().view(np.uint8), the setter for the child class is getting called and is there a way to avoid it?
Thanks in advance
